# Writing data using Moq.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I'm attempting to use [Moq.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/MichalJankowskii/Moq.EntityFrameworkCore) for unit testing. I'm having no problem with query operations that read the pre-seeded data. However write operations initially appear to work without throwing any exceptions but the underlying `DbSet`'s don't reflect any newly added records. Any ideas what I may be missing to moq the write operations?

My moq db context setup code:

```
var dbContextMock = new Mock<MyDbContext>();

var submitterOperators = new List<SubmitterOperator>();
submitterOperators.Add(
    fixture.Build<SubmitterOperator>()
        .With(e => e.Deleted, false)
        .Without(e => e.Operation)
        .Create()
);
dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.SubmitterOperators).ReturnsDbSet(submitterOperators);

return dbContextMock.Object;
```

Code that tries to insert a new entity, that works successfully against an actual non-moq'd database:

```
await _dataContext.SubmitterOperators.AddAsync(entity);
await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But doesn't actually change the moq'd `DbSet<SubmitterOperator>` when unit testing.

I imagine I'm missing some scaffolding somewhere setting up my `dbContextMock` but I haven't found any examples to follow online around moq'ing data writes.

Comment: Don't mock EF Core `DbContext`, instead use In-Memory provider or SQLite provider with "in-memory" option or use actual database to test EF Core queries. Notice that tests with actual database will provide better feedback and confidence than mocks and in-memory solutions.